# Is there a new version of RDL Schema for SQL Server 2012 (denali)?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, rdl, sql-server-2012

All previous versions of SQL Server (including Reporting Services) introduced new RDL schema, which was not supported by current version of report viewer control (included in Visual Studio). Is it true also for version 2012?

For example SQL server 2008 R2 uses RDL 2010 but report viewer control for Visual Studio 2010 supports only RDL 2008 (used by SQL Server 2008).

**Edit**
It seems that SQL2012 uses the same reportbuilder (3.0) as SQL2008R2 [Report Builder (SSRS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213578.aspx). This could indicate that the schema is the same.

Note
RDL Schema version can be found in xmlns attribute of `<Report>` element in .rdl file (usulaly second line of the .rdl file opened in text editor) see [Find the Report Definition Schema Version (SSRS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627465.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSRS 2012 uses the "2010" schema introduced with SSRS 2008 R2.  Remember that the ReportViewer control for Visual Studio is "a version behind", since it's a VS control and not a SQL one.

The newest version of the ReportViewer control is included with the Visual Studio 2011 beta and I think it supports SSRS 2008 R2/2012 (i.e. the 2010 schema).

[You can grab the XSD for the 2010 schema here](http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition/).